# Angular resend the request after change the token

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jwt

I have auth interceptor and JWT authentication.
When token expires im getting 401 and i need to send request to refresh token.
After the token is refreshed i want to resend the user request but it is not working.

For example, to go to my account tab, user need to have valid token,he click on my account and get 401 and then the refresh token is sent and the valid token is saved in the local storage.

Now what i want that after this the interceptor auto make the action of the user, in this case to go to my account but my way doesnt working, how can i do this?

The interceptor:

```
'responseError': function(rejection) {
    var $state = $injector.get('$state');
    var deffer = $q.defer();
    if (rejection.status === 401) {
        var $http = $injector.get('$http');
        var AuthService = $injector.get('AuthService');
        var user = store.get('user');
        var cred = AuthService.refreshTokenValue(user.secretId, user.secretClient, user.refreshToken);
        AuthService.getRefreshToken(cred).then(function(res) {
            UserService.oAuth.accessToken = res.data.access_token;

            // here i want to resend the request
            return deffer.resolve(rejection);
        });

    }

    return $q.reject(rejection);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should first create a promise object to return then retry  request using $http(rejection.config),
resolve or reject promise according to your authorization process.

Sample Code

```
var $state = $injector.get('$state');

 var retryRequest = function($http, config, deferred) {
        function successCallback(response) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }
        function errorCallback(response) {
            deferred.reject(response);
        }
        $http(config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
    }

if (rejection.status === 401) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(); //moved deferred to here
    var $http = $injector.get('$http');
    var AuthService = $injector.get('AuthService');
    var user = store.get('user');
    var cred = AuthService.refreshTokenValue(user.secretId, user.secretClient, user.refreshToken);
    AuthService.getRefreshToken(cred).then(function(res) {
        UserService.oAuth.accessToken = res.data.access_token;
        retryRequest($http, rejection.config, deferred);
        // here i want to resend the request
        return deffer.resolve(rejection);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

return $q.reject(rejection);
```

but you should better use an httpBuffer to queue requests and retry them all once authorization succeeds

Edit: you can use something like this https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth/blob/master/src/http-auth-interceptor.js